# Rank of matrices over Z[X,Y]

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, commutative-algebra

I have $n$ integer matrices, $A_1$ up to $A_n$ in $\mathbb{Z}^{m\times m}$ given. Also, I have an integer vector $(k_1, k_2 , \dots k_n) \in \mathbb{Z}^n$.

Consider the matrix $M = X_1 A_1 + X_2 A_2 + \dots + X_n A_n$ over the ring $\mathbb{Z}[X_1, \dots X_n]$. For any evaluation of $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ such that $b = k_1X_1 + k_2X_2 + \dots + k_nX_n \neq 0$ it is known that the rank of the matrix $M$ is at least $d$.

Does this imply that there exist matrices $P_1,P_2$ over $\mathbb{Z}[X_1, X_2, \dots , X_n]$ with determinant $1$ or $-1$, i.e. every evaluation lies in $\text{GL}(m , \mathbb{Z})$, such that

$$P_1 M P_2 = \begin{pmatrix}m_1b & 0 & \dots & 0 & \ast \\ \ast & m_2b & \dots & 0 & \ast \\ \ast & \ast & \ddots & 0 & \ast \\ \ast &\ast & \dots & m_db & \ast \\ \ast & \ast & \dots & \ast &\end{pmatrix} $$

for $m_1, \dots m_n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

In other words, I am asking whether I can find $d$ linearly independent vectors simply by evaluating $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ in a point for which $b = k_1X_1 + k_2X_2 + \dots + k_nX_n \neq 0$. (In fact, slightly stronger than this, but answering this would be a good start.)

As an example,
$$\begin{pmatrix}0& -X& -Y & 0 \\ X & 0 & 0&0\\ Y&0&0&2X\\ 0&0&-2X&0 \end{pmatrix} $$
has rank $4$ if $X \neq 0$. Indeed, up to rearanging columns and rows, we get the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}2X& Y& 0 & 0 \\ 0 & X & 0&0\\ 0&0&-X&-Y\\ 0&0&0&-2X \end{pmatrix} .$$
Or for example, if $X-Y \neq 0$, then the matrix below has rank at least $2$:
$$\begin{pmatrix}0& 2Y& 0 & -X \\ -2Y & 0 & -X&0\\ 0&X&0&-Y\\ X&0&Y&0 \end{pmatrix} .$$
Indeed, under the condition $X-Y \neq 0$, we can always get the following linearly independent vectors:
$$\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ -2Y+X\\ 0 \\ X-Y\end{pmatrix},\quad \begin{pmatrix} 2Y-X\\ 0 \\ X-Y \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} .$$